# Conditional cumulative sum as array-formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have one column with values of which I list the cumulative sum in the results-column. But this needs to happen separately for the three (sorted) categories in the second column!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZcPu.png)

See the example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MF1cQ_V-RaDzVRCBbLdXbELJTxeukfUOIaX_w4P-aJo/edit?usp=sharing).

I have been trying since hours to solve this rather simple problem without success. Since the formula will be part of an already pretty extensive array-formula it's

1. Mandatory to be an array-formula
2. Best if we can get it to work without further `=if()` questioning

It's very very simple to solve this with a drag-down formula but I can't translate this in to an array-formula for some reason!

`=SUMIF($B$2:B2,$B$2:B2,$A$2:A2)`

Comment: not exactly sure how you want the output, in the `???` cell. do you want only A? only B? All?  What should the answer be?

Comment: Output should be the same as column E, right beside! This column is populated by the drag-down formula. My mission: create the same output with an array-formula. ;-)
thx for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sheet 'JP' in your shared spreadsheet, I entered in D2

```
=ArrayFormula((IF(LEN(A2:A), SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A),)))
```

See if that works?

EDIT: for a cumulative sum per category, try this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B100), mmult({mmult(if(B2:B100<>"A", 0,transpose(if(transpose(row(B2:B100))>=row(B2:B100),(B2:B100="A")*(A2:A100), 0))), row(B2:B100)^0), mmult(if(B2:B100<>"B", 0,transpose(if(transpose(row(B2:B100))>=row(B2:B100), (B2:B100="B")*(A2:A100), 0))), row(B2:B100)^0) , mmult(if(B2:B100<>"C", 0,transpose(if(transpose(row(B2:B100))>=row(B2:B100), (B2:B100="C")*(A2:A100), 0))), row(B2:B100)^0)}, {1;1;1}),))
```

I also added this formula to the sheet you shared.

Comment: This formula calculates the cumulative sum of column A, irrespective of the category. We need to tell the formula to do this only for the specific category in column B. So we need some kind of combination between your formula (I added it in the sheet in column C, thx!!) and the formula next to it (Column D).
Again: The desired output is the one in column E, we just need to get it done with a different formula!

Comment: Hi @gazeto: I updated my answer. See if this works for you. Note that this formula might not by very 'resource-friendly' when used on open arrays (with a lot of rows).

Comment: Impressive construction^^ Thanks a lot – I'll have a close look and will share in case I find a way to simplify the formula/make it faster. (sry, can't really upvote because I lack reputation).

Comment: @JPV, Could you explain how your first formula works? I'm completely puzzled.... It's a great solution but I would like to understand how it works.

Comment: Wait a minute! Did you hard code the categories? aw shiet. I have like 16 categories!

Comment: @Ivan: Assuming you'd want to have a running sum per category you could try =ArrayFormula(if(B2:B="",,mmult((B2:B=transpose(B2:B))*(row(B2:B)>= TRANSPOSE(row(B2:B)))*(transpose(A2:A)),row(B2:B)^0))) Also see the cell with green backtground in the spreadsheet OP shared.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I've… I've tried so hard to make this formula all by myself FOR YEARS and then I saw your comment… THANK YOU!!!